# Strengtheing a weak bed frame

Tags: statics, stability

I bought a 200x90 sq.cm. bed and assembled it. The bed frame is assembled out of hollow iron rods. After using for a few days I started having back pain. So I checked the bed and found that some of those rods got bent in the middle and that made the whole frame uneven. I want to strengthen it, however I don't have much stuff at hand, and we are in a lockdown due to coronavirus.

I have not thrown out the wooden planks from my older bed. So I thought putting them on the bars will distribute the load and may help it. My question is what is the pattern that will provide maximum strength? I arranged them in a way (see picture) and it already fills quite solid. I will appreciate any feedback. For information, I don't have an electronic drill machine or any such thing; also I don't know how to use them.

Thank you for reading, it is my first post here. :) Note: I also posted this question in home improvement stack exchange, just fyi.
[image]

Comment: Cross posted on Home Improvement - where it belongs : https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/187547/97780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take the wooden slats from the old bed and cut them so they can stand on end and be trapped between the steel tubing and the floor, thereby supporting the load that the steel tubing by itself cannot. If you wish, you can cut a round notch in one end of the slat so as to capture the tubing; this will help prevent the slats from popping out of position.